# Inserting data in Entity Framework, need for using State.Unchanged

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

My first question here, so please bear with me :)

I am building a ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web Application and try to use the Entity Framework and keep stumpling into a case where I need to explicitly tell the framework that I don't want to insert an existing object. Specifically, I have a function that takes in a Person object that I want to assign as author of a new case. The person exists in the database, and the organization that the person belongs to does also exist. If I do not have the first two lines, the SaveChangesAsync function fails on a Unique Constraint (assuming that the EF is trying to insert rows into Person and Organization tables). Can it really be true that I have to keep track of this all time? Or what am I doing wrong? Any help is very much appreciated! Thanks.

```
_context.Entry(author).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
_context.Entry(author.Org).State = EntityState.Unchanged;       

var c = new Case
{
   IsDraft = true,
   Organization = author.Org,
   Author = author
};
```

Comment: you can set both as `null` or context.Entry(yourEntityName).Property(x => x.author).IsModified = false;

Comment: But I want to assign the new Case with the Person I am passing in. If I set it to null, I dont achieve that. And I dont see how context.Entry(yourEntityName).Property(x => x.author).IsModified = false is any better than what I am already doing?

Comment: what about making property private with only get

Comment: It seems, I have not explained my problem good enough. I want to create a new row in the table Case where some of the columns are foreign keys. In SQL, I would do something like INSERT INTO Case (is_draft, org_id, person_id) VALUES (0, 4, 5) (assuming the Org Id is 4 and the Person Id is 5). I would like to do something similar here, now that I get an object Author of that is from the Person table. It has a PersonId (which is the value 5, and it has a foreign key OrgId which has the value 4). I hoped that I could just create the Case without explicitly telling EF the 2 first lines

Comment: @ClausBehn Not if you call `Add(case)`. There are some improvements in EF Core 2 when you call `Update` though. So if the `Case` entity is using auto generated key, then you can try using `Update` instead of `Add`, which in this case will work as Insert Or Update, according to the documentation. But the way you are doing is safer IMO. See [Disconnected entities](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities), [Basic Save](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/basic) and [Saving Related Data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data) topics.